# UIImageView not showing on top of MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage, mapkit

In IB, I have added a UIImageView on top of MKMapView(which spans the whole screen above the bottom tab bar). The UIImageView shall represent the map legend.

I have created an IBOutlet for the UIImageView and have synthesized it in the .m file of my mapViewController. I am setting the image programmatically using the following line of code:

```
[legend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maplegend.png"]];
```

I want this image to be there all the time at the bottom right corner of the MKMapView.

But no image is being displayed when I run my project.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the same problem. I solved it by putting the views next to each other instead of over each other in the view hierarchy.

The view hierarchy would then look like this

- containerView (`UIView`)

  - mapView (`MKMapView`)
  - myBanner (`UIImageView`)

(`containerView.subviews == @[mapView, myBanner]` in this case)

myBanner can still overlap mapView, because views with a higher index will be placed above views with a lower index.

This would not work:

- containerView (`UIView`)

  - myBanner (`UIImageView`)
  - mapView (`MKMapView`)

I'm not 100% sure, but I think there is a problem with the `MKMapView`: it just doesn't want you to put subviews on top of it.

If you also want your legend to be click-throughable (i.e. not accepting touch-events), you would have to create your own `UIView` subclass for the `containerView` and override the `-hitTest:withEvent:` method...

Comment: Ah! I was doing the same thing as you have suggested but the image was  getting hidden by the bottom tab bar. Your answer is correct. Thanks!